# Parallel second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I wonder if the following statement is true: If $M^n$ is a smooth complete submanifold of $\mathbb R^{n+p}$ with $\nabla A=0,$ where $A$ is the second fundamental form of $M,$ then $M=S^k\times\mathbb R^{n-k}$ for some $k.$

By Lawson's theorem in $\textit{Local Rigidity Theorems for Minimal Hypersurfaces},$ we know that the statement is true when $M$ is a hypersurface (i.e., $p=1$), but I am not sure if it is true in the higher codimension case.

Any ideas or comments are appreciated!

Comment: I think $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1 \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ has constant second funfamental form. I may be wrong.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the comment! Let me check it immediately.

Comment: @Didier I am not quite sure but it seems to me that the norm of $A$ is constant, but $A$ itself is not. I calculate that its mean curvature vector is the position vector (up to a sign), which is the trace of $A,$ so $A$ could not be constant.

Comment: Apologies, I meant "parallel", that is $\nabla A=0$ for the induced Levi-Civita connexion. Of course I may be wrong. Note that even in the sphere case $S^{n-1}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $A$ is not "constant" and have mean curvature vector parallel to the position vector, even if $\nabla A = 0$.

Comment: You are completely right. Let me check its derivative.

Comment: I found [this article](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-032-01/S0002-9939-1972-0290298-8/S0002-9939-1972-0290298-8.pdf) that may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I need to add another condition to make this statement holds.

Comment: @Didier Do you think the conclusion of the original question hold if we further assume $M$ has a flat normal bundle?